# How to remove foreign key constraint in sql server?

Tags: sql-server, database, foreign-keys

I want to remove foreign key from another table so i can insert values of my choice.

I am new in databases so please tell me correct sql query to drop or remove foreign key value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I drop a foreign key in SQL Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/93264/how-do-i-drop-a-foreign-key-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 175, accepted):

Try following

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> DROP CONSTRAINT <FOREIGN_KEY_NAME>
```

Refer : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp

Comment: I haven't added any constraint name. how do I delete that constraint?

Comment: Even if you don't specify the constrain name SQL Server will assign a unique constrain name. You can find the name with SQL Management Studio.

Comment: @Nytux The OP clearly stated that the platform is MS SQL Server, not PostgreSQL (tags and question title).

Answer (score 15):

Its wrong to do that in refer to [referential integrity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Referential_integrity), because once its broken its not easy to turn it on again without having to go through the records and delete the ones which breaks the constraints.

Anyway the Syntax is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE Tablename DROP CONSTRAINT ContName;
```

See MSDN:

- [Delete Primary Keys](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190621.aspx)
- [Delete Foreign Key Relationships](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189579.aspx)

Comment: No, the syntax in SQL Server for dropping Foreign Key and Primary Key are the same: alter table <tablename> drop constraint <fk_or_pk_name>

Comment: @demoncodemonkey  ContName or <fk_or_pk_name> should be the column name in the existing table or the column name from the original table which we are using as a foreign key in the current one?

Comment: @iatharva it's the name of the constraint - for example PK_Users_Id or FK_Users_Id etc. You can view all the foreign keys in your database using `SELECT name FROM sys.foreign_keys`. Good luck!

Answer (score 6):

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName] DROP CONSTRAINT [CONSTRAINT_NAME]
```

But, be careful man, once you do that, you may never get a chance back, and you should read some basic database book see why we need foreign key

Comment: He can just add the constraint again if he wants it back, as long as the referential integrity is still there. If it isn't, that has to be fixed anyway.

Comment: @Tobberoth, yes, that what I meant, thanks for made it clear. In the real world most of the time some other developer will mess up the data in the table and you can't add the constraint back due to those data there.

Answer (score 5):

To remove all the constraints from the DB:

```
SELECT 'ALTER TABLE ' + Table_Name  +' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + Constraint_Name
FROM Information_Schema.CONSTRAINT_TABLE_USAGE
```

Answer (score 3):

You should consider (temporarily) disabling the constraint before you completely delete it.

If you look at the table creation TSQL you will see something like:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[dbAccounting] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_some_FK_constraint]
```

You can run

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[dbAccounting] NOCHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_some_FK_constraint]
```

... then insert/update a bunch of values that violate the constraint, and then turn it back on by running the original `CHECK` statement.

(I have had to do this to cleanup poorly designed systems I've inherited in the past.)

Answer (score 3):

Drop all the foreign keys of a table:

```
USE [Database_Name]
DECLARE @FOREIGN_KEY_NAME VARCHAR(100)

DECLARE FOREIGN_KEY_CURSOR CURSOR FOR
SELECT name FOREIGN_KEY_NAME FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE parent_object_id = (SELECT object_id FROM sys.objects WHERE name = 'Table_Name' AND TYPE = 'U')

OPEN FOREIGN_KEY_CURSOR
----------------------------------------------------------
FETCH NEXT FROM FOREIGN_KEY_CURSOR INTO @FOREIGN_KEY_NAME
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN
       DECLARE @DROP_COMMAND NVARCHAR(150) = 'ALTER TABLE Table_Name DROP CONSTRAINT' + ' ' + @FOREIGN_KEY_NAME

       EXECUTE Sp_executesql @DROP_COMMAND

       FETCH NEXT FROM FOREIGN_KEY_CURSOR INTO @FOREIGN_KEY_NAME

    END
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
CLOSE FOREIGN_KEY_CURSOR
DEALLOCATE FOREIGN_KEY_CURSOR
```

Comment: you are wrong with **parent_object_id** ... it should be used instate of that **referenced_object_id**

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the **DB** you are using there's a syntax or another.

If you're using **Oracle** you have to put what the other users told you:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP CONSTRAINT fk_name;
```

But if you use **MySQL** then this will give you a syntax error, instead you can type:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name DROP INDEX fk_name;
```

Answer (score 2):

firstly use

```sql
show create table table_name;
```

to see the descriptive structure of your table.

There you may see constraints respective to foreign keys you used in that table.
First delete the respective constraint with

```sql
alter table table_name drop constraint constraint_name;
```

and then delete the respective foreign keys or column you wanted...GoodLuck!!

Answer (score 1):

```sql
ALTER TABLE table
DROP FOREIGN KEY fk_key
```

EDIT: didn't notice you were using sql-server, my bad

```sql
ALTER TABLE table
DROP CONSTRAINT fk_key
```

Answer (score 1):

Use those queries to find all FKs:

```
Declare @SchemaName VarChar(200) = 'Schema Name'
Declare @TableName VarChar(200) = 'Table name'

-- Find FK in This table.
SELECT 
    'IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + 
      '[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + '].[' + FK.name + ']' 
      + ''') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + 
      '[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + '].[' 
      + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + ']' + ''')) ' +

    'ALTER TABLE ' +  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) +
    '.[' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + 
    '] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + FK.name
    , S.name , O.name, OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id)
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS FK
INNER JOIN Sys.objects As O 
  ON (O.object_id = FK.parent_object_id )
INNER JOIN SYS.schemas AS S 
  ON (O.schema_id = S.schema_id)  
WHERE 
      O.name = @TableName
      And S.name = @SchemaName


-- Find the FKs in the tables in which this table is used
  SELECT 
    ' IF  EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.foreign_keys WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + 
      '[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + '].[' + FK.name + ']' 
      + ''') AND parent_object_id = OBJECT_ID(N''' + 
      '[' + OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + '].[' 
      + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + ']' + ''')) ' +

    ' ALTER TABLE ' +  OBJECT_SCHEMA_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) +
    '.[' + OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id) + 
    '] DROP CONSTRAINT ' + FK.name
    , S.name , O.name, OBJECT_NAME(FK.parent_object_id)
FROM sys.foreign_keys AS FK
INNER JOIN Sys.objects As O 
  ON (O.object_id = FK.referenced_object_id )
INNER JOIN SYS.schemas AS S 
  ON (O.schema_id = S.schema_id)  
WHERE 
      O.name = @TableName
      And S.name = @SchemaName
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can also delete a Foreign Key Constraint from the SQL Server Management Studio itself. *You can try it if the commands do not work*.

1. Expand your database view.
2. Right Click on Table which has foreign key constraint. Choose Design. A tab with the information about table columns will open.
3. Right click on the column which has the foreign key reference. Or you can right click on any column. Choose Relationships.
4. A list of relationships will appear (if you have one) in a pop up window.
5. From there you can delete the foreign key constraint.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

If you find yourself in a situation where the FK name of a table has been auto-generated and you aren't able to view what it exactly is (in the case of not having rights to a database for instance) you could try something like this:

```
DECLARE @table NVARCHAR(512), @sql NVARCHAR(MAX);
SELECT @table = N'dbo.Table';
SELECT @sql = 'ALTER TABLE ' + @table
    + ' DROP CONSTRAINT ' + NAME + ';'
    FROM sys.foreign_keys
    WHERE [type] = 'F'
    AND [parent_object_id] = OBJECT_ID(@table);
EXEC sp_executeSQL @sql;
```

Build up a stored proc which drops the constraint of the specified table without specifying the actual FK name. It drops the constraint where the object `[type]` is equal to F (Foreign Key constraint).

**Note**: if there are multiple FK's in the table it will drop them all. So this solution works best if the table you are targeting has just one FK.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't know foreign key constraint name then try this to find it.

```
sp_help 'TableName'
```

additionally for different schema

```
sp_help 'schemaName.TableName'
```

then

```
ALTER TABLE <TABLE_NAME> DROP CONSTRAINT <FOREIGN_KEY_NAME>
```

Answer (score 0):

To be on the safer side, just name all your constraints and take note of them in the comment section.

```
ALTER TABLE[table_name]
DROP CONSTRAINT Constraint_name
```

Comment: if you forgot to name your constraint(s), phpMyAdmin gives any of your constraints you used a unique name. To check this given unique name by phpMyAdmin:Click on INFORMATION_SCHEMA tap on the left hand side of your workbench. After this, scroll down and locate TABLE_CONSTRAINTS and click on it. There you will see all the constraints set on the various columns and their names and other details.

Answer (score -6):

```
alter table <referenced_table_name> drop  primary key;
```

Foreign key constraint will be removed.

Comment: Dropping the referenced table's primary key is perhaps the worst way to try fixing the issue. Oh wait - dropping the referenced table itself might be worse.

Comment: This avoids the essence of the question posed