# I want to add records to the table but there is a duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-insert, unique-index

I have a table named Car and I want to add this records;

```
insert into Car 
values 
 ('a', 'a'), ('a', 'b'), ('a', 'c'),('b', 'b'), ('b', 'c'), ('c', 'd'), ('d', 'd');
```

I got this massage: ( ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry 'a' for key a)

so how I can fix it?

Comment: Adhere to the table structure, if the column is any key then you cannot insert duplicate to that column

Comment: So, what is the solving?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: Duplicate entry '' for key 'email'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33673946/error-duplicate-entry-for-key-email)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have defined either a Primary Key or a Unique Key on the first column of the Car table.
Either redefine the table without the Primary Key or Drop the Index.  See demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df31c950dbba0cff22b8ad0300dce7b9).
Another possibility is that you intended the unique key to be a composite of the two fields, in which case you need to amend your CREATE UNIQUE INDEX, as also shown in the demo.