# How to disable all constraints(foreign key,Primary key,IDENTITY) in MS SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, foreign-keys

I have created one database by executing generated script(schema).

After that I am copying database,only data while copying I facing problem of **foreign key violation and primary key violation**

What should I do for this issue.

> key Violation

Comment: If you are actually copying a database, then you'd be much better off just using Backup/Restore.  It's much simpler, faster, and less error-prone.

Comment: How are you copying the data?

Comment: first create database using ddl then copy data

Answer (score 0):

You really only have two options here, go though the data your importing and change the conflicting value or drop the constrains all together. Once the data is in the new DB you can not enable constraints until you address the duplicate data. See this SO for in on removing FKs, it also applies to dropping PKs

[How do I drop a foreign key in SQL Server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93264/how-do-i-drop-a-foreign-key-in-sql-server)

I would highly recommend seeing if you can change the data so it no longer violates the key constrains